# OpenSSL Errors SSL operation

Tags: php, ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I have a strange problem. Before 2 days my script work ok, but today my site stop working and show me this message "SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:140940E5:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:ssl handshake failure". There are no changes made these days. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post the exact URL you are using to connect to the server, and post the output of `openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:<port> -tls1 -servername <hostname>`. Do so by adding it to your question by clicking *Edit* (and don't post it as a comment). Otherwise, we can't reproduce it and there's not enough information to help troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The host has probably recently disabled SSL3. If you're specifying the CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, comment it out.